# Akka Actor hotswapping using rest api

Tags: scala, akka, spray, hotswap

Upon calling a rest api, I would want to switch the actor's routing to another routes.
Please see the below code.

Couple of questions:

1. The code compiles fine but when the app is started and a http call is made, I get Configured registration timeout of 1 second expired, stopping message and i dont get any response from server.
2. I want to be able to switch routing to another set of routes through api.

made

```
package com.example
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.io.IO
import spray.httpx.RequestBuilding._
import spray.http.MediaTypes._
import spray.routing.{RoutingSettings, RejectionHandler, ExceptionHandler, HttpService}
import spray.util.LoggingContext
import scala.concurrent.Future
import spray.can.Http
import spray.http._
import akka.util.Timeout
import HttpMethods._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.event.Logging
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case object Swap
class MyServiceActor extends Actor with MyService with akka.actor.ActorLogging {

  implicit def actorRefFactory = context
  import context._

  def receive = {
      case Swap =>
           become {
             case Swap => unbecome()
             case _    => runRoute(otherRoutes)
           }
      case _ =>   runRoute(myRoute)
  } 
}


trait MyService extends HttpService { this: MyServiceActor =>

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(15.seconds)

  implicit val system = context.system

  val myRoute =
  {
    path("") {
      get {
          complete("MyRoute")
      }
    } ~ path("swap") {

        get{
            self ! Swap
            complete("Swapped")
        }
    }
  }

  val otherRoutes =path("") {
  get {
      complete("OtherRoutes")
     }
   } ~ path("swap") {
        get{
        self ! Swap
        complete("Reverted")
     }
}

}
```

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem. The error message you are getting seems to suggest that your actor isn't handling the `Connected` message for some reason.

Comment: If i change the receive method to def receive =runRoute(myRoute) the server responds without any problem.

Comment: Yes, and the other answer explains why: you need to pass the actual message through the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

runRoute is a partially applied function, so you can't just write `runRoute(routeName)` to call it - it will just return another function (which handles routes) but without calling it; you should pass the request object explicitly:

```
def receive = {
      case Swap =>
           become {
             case Swap => unbecome()
             case x    => val f = runRoute(otherRoutes); f(x)
           }
      case x => val f = runRoute(myRoute); f(x)
  }
```

`runRoute(route)` returns function which handle "Connected" message. So that's why you're getting "registration timeout" error - you don't return this function from receive method. When you write `def receive = runRoute(route)` this function is used as handler and everything is fine. But when you write `def receive = {case _ => runRoute(route)}` nothing happens - `receive` function do nothing because function returned by `runRoute(route)` goes nowhere.

See, https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/HttpService.scala

And also you can call become/unbecome right from your route because you already have MyServiceActor as self-type. When you use separate `Swap` message - actor may change its role a little bit after you receive successful "Swapped" response (role changing will occur asynchronously)

```
case object Swap
class MyServiceActor extends Actor with MyService with akka.actor.ActorLogging {

  implicit def actorRefFactory = context
  import context._

  def swapped = {
      case x => val f = runRoute(otherRoutes); f(x)
  }

  def receive = {
      case x => val f = runRoute(myRoute); f(x)
  } 
}


trait MyService extends HttpService { this: MyServiceActor =>

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(15.seconds)

  implicit val system = context.system

  val myRoute = {
    pathSingleSlash {
      get {
            complete("MyRoute")
      }
    } ~ path("swap") {
        get {
            become(swapped)
            complete("Swapped")
        }
    }
  }

  val otherRoutes = { 
   pathSingleSlash {
     get {
      complete("OtherRoutes")
     }
   } ~ path("swap") {
     get{
        unbecome()
        complete("Reverted")
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Updated: your path matchers are also incorrect. Use:

```
 pathSingleSlash {
   ...
 } ~ path("swap") {
     ...
 }
```

or

```
 path("swap") {
     ...
 } ~ path("") { //matches everything else
     ...
 }
```

Updated2:

Make sure that your actor registered as singleton in your Main:

```
import akka.io.IO
import spray.can.Http

implicit val system = ActorSystem()

val myListener: ActorRef = Props[MyServiceActor]

IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(myListener, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
```

http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-can/http-server/#http-server

Comment: I had to pass the defaults explicitly
runRoute(otherRoutes)(ExceptionHandler.default, RejectionHandler.Default, context,
    RoutingSettings.default, LoggingContext.fromActorRefFactory)(x)

Comment: I expected after hitting swap the first time "http://localhost:8080/swap" otherRoutes would be used but myRoute is continued to be used and "MyRoute" is displayed on the browser. What am i missing here ?

Comment: about implicits: you could do `val f = runRoute(otherRoutes); f(x)` instead

Comment: use `pathSingleSlash` instead of `path("")` because `path("")` matches all possible pathes: http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/predefined-directives-alphabetically/

Comment: another option - put `path("swap")` as the first matcher (switch places with `path("")`)

Comment: I changed path("swap") as the first matcher but i think thats not the issue.The problem is val myRoute is being used even after calling  self ! Swap. The behaviour of the actor is not getting changed.

Comment: 1. did you ever really received "Swapped" responce? 

2.See also "And also you can call become/unbecome right from your route ..." from my response - you don't have to pass "Swap" message to the actor

Comment: just call become/unbecome directly from your routes

Comment: also, make sure that your actor is singleton

Comment: context.become should be called from complete block

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem, then you can set the server paras larger to reslove the problem

enter code here

```
val backlog = 50000
val standardConfig = ServerSettings("spray.can.server.ssl-encryption = off, spray.can.server.registration-timeout = 5s")
val config = standardConfig.copy(serverHeader = "REST API", sslEncryption = false, remoteAddressHeader = true)
val serviceActor = system.actorOf(Props[ApiServiceActor], "apiServiceActor")
IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(serviceActor, interface = "0.0.0.0", ConfigurationHelper.Port, settings = Some(config), backlog = backlog)
```